# Just updated to Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite and Wi-Fi is always looking for a network

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, osx-yosemite

Just updated to Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite and Wi-Fi states that it is *always* looking for a network even when it is already connected to a Wi-Fi. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

How do I stop it from `Looking for Networks`? It is connected. I feel like this draining my battery for no good reason.

Comment: @Jake how would you go about testing this hypothesis? Sounds like you may be on to something. I would like to be sure. Is their a tool? Maybe wireshark could be used to listen for Wifi scanning activity? Would be interested to know how to investigate if you know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you open that drop down, it will start looking. It automatically assumes that because you've opened the menu, you're looking to change network, even if you're connected. It won't do it when you're connected if the network drop down is closed.

Comment: Thats interesting.. How do you know this to be true? Or are you speculating? Thats a poor design choice in my opinion. Doesn't feel natural..

Comment: On my MacBook, it takes a few seconds before kicking in the Looking for networks status, which would say to me that it only happens when the drop down is open. Else it would be instant in my opinion

Comment: That’s how it is and this isn’t even new behavior. It used to do this on Mavericks, too.

Comment: It happened to me on Mavericks too - thats why I'm so convinced!

Comment: Well mine cycles between "on" and "looking for networks" it does so about every 2-3 seconds when the menu is open. How about you guys? Same behavior? I don't recall this in Mavericks. I did have connection issues from sleep in mavericks.. So far appears ok here so I'm happy about that :)

Comment: Kind of @fab, yeah

Comment: @fab My Mountain Lion machine does that, and I'm pretty sure Lion did as well.  I find I notice old behaviours for the first time whenever I update the OS.

Comment: Conclusion drawn then!

Comment: I guess its a poor ux choice..